# Should Android KeyHash depend only on PC generating it, not methods or phones?

Tags: android, facebook, android-keystore

I am having an issue about generating Android KeyHash with debug.keystore that I don't quite understand.

What I understand is that if I generate a KeyHash on my PC no matter how I generate it, it should give me a unique keyhash. And I can bring this keyhash for integration with Facebook SDK.

However, what I found out is the following:

1. I use the following command line suggested on Facebook developer page:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
>   with password: android

And I obtained the following keyHash : E3P3dslAkuReIuFQJC5oTlhkRrs=

2. I then use the following method I found on StackOverflow:

> In order to generate key hash you need to follow some easy steps.
>
> 1) Download Openssl from: here.
>
> 2) Make a openssl folder in C drive
>
> 3) Extract Zip files into this openssl folder created in C Drive.
>
> 4) Copy the File debug.keystore from .android folder in my case (C:\Users\SYSTEM.android) and paste into JDK bin Folder in my case (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin)
>
> 5) Open command prompt and give the path of JDK Bin folder in my case (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin).
>
> 6) Copy the following code and hit enter
>
> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore > c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt
>
> 7) Now you need to enter password, Password = android.
>
> 8) If you see in openssl Bin folder, you will get a file with the name of debug.txt
>
> 9) Now either you can restart command prompt or work with existing command prompt
>
> 10) get back to C drive and give the path of openssl Bin folder
>
> 11) copy the following code and paste
>
> openssl sha1 -binary debug.txt > debug_sha.txt
>
> 12) you will get debug_sha.txt in openssl bin folder
>
> 13) Again copy following code and paste
>
> openssl base64 -in debug_sha.txt > debug_base64.txt
>
> 14) you will get debug_base64.txt in openssl bin folder
>
> 15) open debug_base64.txt file Here is your Key hash.
>
> with password: android

And I obtained the following keyHash :  zp+a+1HT9jLTgob9Htw9EFrZatY=

Both of these methods are generated on the **same PC** and with the **same debug.keystore**. Why are they not the same? Aren't they supposed to be the same?

Another issue is KeyHash I obtained with an android code on different phones. I use the following code (again found on the StackOverflow):

```
public static void showHashKey(Context context) {  
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.loginfb", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); //Your package name here
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { 
    }
}
```

Then I checked on the log window with two different phones, what I found is the following:

> LG phone Android 2.3
>   12-09 09:22:51.832: I/KeyHash:(20572): NlsbfhmR2/ZCXnpKNNsH+0II8LM=
>
> Samsung phone Android 4.2.2
>   12-09 09:51:21.054: I/KeyHash:(20067): zp+a+1HT9jLTgob9Htw9EFrZatY=

They gave me different HashKeys. However, one of them (zp+a+1HT9jLTgob9Htw9EFrZatY=) is consistent with the second method above.

Anyone knows what is happening here? I am really confused for quite some times.

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

The key hash is from the key used to sign the APK.

For your debugging sessions, the default debug key is used.

Usually when you release your app to the public, you use another key. Therefore the key hash is different.

Comment: I have not obtained KeyHash with release keystore at this point. What I have done is only work with debug.keystore while developing my application.

Comment: Just for the integration to Facebook SDK, the programmatic method (showKeyHash) is more accurate

Comment: They should be the same, very probably the keystore you access through command is not the same as the keystore you used to export the APK

Comment: I am certain that keystore is the same one. I double checked several times.